# prevent bot from replying to an already replied tweet?

Tags: python, api, twitter, bots, tweepy

Is it possible to have a list to store the ID's of recent tweets that the bot replied to instead of saving it in a text file?

```
def on_status(self, status):
timelineTweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name="USERNAME")
alreadyReplied = [-1]

if timelineTweets[0].id not in alreadyReplied:
    lastTweet = timelineTweets[0]
    api.update_status('@USERNAME' + gettext(), in_reply_to_status_id=lastTweet.id)
    alreadyReplied.append(lastTweet.id)
    if len(alreadyReplied) == 20:
        alreadyReplied.pop()
    return True
```

Comment: Saving to a file means that the bot can be restarted and can then read the already replied tweets instead of loosing that data?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes but i am not very concerened about the data. my main concern is that my bot keeps replying to one tweet multiple times, so to prevent that i thought i would save the tweet id's